# Как ввести переменную для программы с клавиатуры? Си

Tags: c, переменные, ввод

Есть простая задачка на поиск корней введенной функции:

```
double f(double x){
    return exp(x) - pow(x,2)- 5;
}

int main() {
    double a, b, d;
    printf("Enter the interval for the function: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &b);
    while (fabs(f(a) - f(b)) > 0.001){
        d = (a + b)/2;
        if(f(d) > 0){
            b = d;
        }
        else{
            a = d;
        }
        printf("d = %lf\n", d);
        printf("a = %lg, b = %lg\n", a, b);
    }
    printf("The answer of the function is %lf", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Как правильно изменить код, чтобы функцию возможно было вводить с клавиатуры, непосредственно во время работы программы?
Спасибо!

Comment: Для этого придётся писать интерпретатор математических выражений....

Comment: Ввести как текст, переписать в файл, оттранслировать, сделать shared library (.dll в винде, .so в *nix), подгрузить и далее можно вызывать